# Can't perform user authentication with my sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I just got a web application that was transferred to me to finish. I have step my microsoft management studio. The issue i'm having now is that, each time i run my application and i supply a wrong username or password, i get an error message that my login credentials are wrong. but when i supply a correct username and password, i cant the following output from my browser

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL
>   hosts.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 283:    <siteMap>
Line 284:      <providers>
Line 285:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 286:      </providers>
Line 287:    </siteMap>
```

I have searched all through the internet without an answer. What could be the cause?

### connection string

```
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=MCBALOO;Initial Catalog=SmartDeskDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password123$" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="SmartDeskDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MCBALOO;Initial Catalog=SmartDeskDb;User ID=sa;Password=password123$" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Please add full error

Comment: Line 283:    <siteMap>
Line 284:      <providers>
Line 285:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 286:      </providers>
Line 287:    </siteMap>

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had to uninstall the mysql connector running on my system for me to access my sql server. Can't say why this is so but it got my issue solved .